# resolving conflict between JAWS and key-press events for navigating large drop-down menus

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, navigation, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have been toiling over this for weeks now, researching solutions that others have developed for fully keyboard-navigable menus (both for sited users that have physical impairments and for non-sighted users that rely on assistive technology such as JAWS).  I have a [drop-down menu script](http://designbymichael.com/test/menu/) that I've built for our state agencies at the State of Minnesota and it works quite well....but I am having one problem:  JAWS has reserved both the use of arrow keys and the space bar.

The example menu I hyperlinked above allows you to navigate through the entire menu one of two ways:  using arrow keys to drill down through the menus and traverse back up again, or using a combination of the tab and shift-tab keys to navigate and the spacebar to toggle the visibility (and accessibility) of submenus.  It works fine when you are just using a browser without JAWS or on the Mac if you use Safari along with VoiceOver. Furthermore with VoiceOver and Safari, you can navigate through the menu with either the arrow keys or the tab keys with space bar to toggle subnavigation visibility.

So I'm at a loss as what to do for JAWS users. What keyboard event can I use to toggle the display of submenus without conflicting with keyboard shortcuts that are reserved by JAWS?

[MENU DEMO](http://designbymichael.com/test/menu/)

Comment: What browser version and Jaws version are you using? With Firefox 31.0 and Jaws 15 I am able to hit enter on the menu which activates forms field. I can use down and right arrow to drill down to level 6 a.

Comment: It was with Internet Explorer 9 and the latest version of JAWS (eval copy).  I had to move the role="menu" to the UL tags and the role="menuitem" to the <a> tags — so that was an error on my part. But here's a bit of confusion...<ul> is supposed to be the menu, but the first level items with submenus don't announce they have a submenu unless you assign role="menu" to each of the first level LI tags.  That can't be right, can it?